# Classify intent of random utterance of chat bot from training data and give different graphical visualization using random forest?

Tags: tensorflow, scikit-learn, nlp, nltk, text-parsing

I am creating a nlp model to detect the intent from the provided utterance from a excel file which I am using for training having 2 columns like shown below:

```
Utterence                                       Intent
hi can I have an Apple Watch                   service
how much I will be paying monthly              service
you still around                              YOU_THERE
are you still there                           YOU_THERE
you there                                     YOU_THERE
Speak to me if you are there.                 YOU_THERE
you around                                    YOU_THERE
```

There are like around 3000 utterances in the training files and many intents.

I trained my model using scikit learn module and my code looks like this.

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import re
def preprocessing(userQuery):
    letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z\\d]", " ", userQuery)
    words = letters_only.lower().split()
    return( " ".join(words ))
#read utterance data from a xlsx file
train = pd.read_excel('training.xlsx')
query_features = train['Utterence']
#create tfidf
tfidf_vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 1))
new_query = [preprocessing(query) for query in query_features]
features = tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(new_query).toarray()
#create random forest classification model
model = RandomForestClassifier()
model.fit(features, train['Intent'])
#intent prediction on user query
userQuery = "I want apple watch"
userQueryList=[]
userQueryList.append(preprocessing(userQuery))
utfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(userQueryList)
print(" prediction: ", model.predict(utfidf))
```

The one of problem for me here is for example: when i run for utterance `I want apple watch` it gives predicted intent as `you_there` instead of `service` as shown below(confirmation on training snapshot above):

```
C:\U\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\forest.py:246: FutureWarning: The default value of n_estimators will change from 10 in version 0.20 to 100 in 0.22.
  "10 in version 0.20 to 100 in 0.22.", FutureWarning)
 prediction:  ['YOU_THERE']
```

Please help me how should i train my  model and what changes should I make to fix such issues and how i can check accuracy? Also I want to see graphical visualization and ROC curve how it can achieved using random forest. I am not very verse in NLP any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You are using word bags approach which does not perform well on sequence data.
For your problem, sequential is material to classification.
I would suggest to you that use LSTM (performs better on sequence data)

Comment: Can you help me show how the same code reflect in LSTM also how can i plot the ROC curve and graph of feature vs predicted valueor if there is any source on Github

Comment: https://github.com/ashokc/word-bags-vs-word-sequences-for-text-classification/blob/master/lstm.py, ignore the first few lines, focus from line number 40 onward

Comment: There is problem statement mentioned and training file as such it is difficult to visualize the problem statement from code. Can you please show in my code at any few places where it can be used, also how could the ROC curve be generated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Let's address your first issue:

> how should i train my model and what changes should I make to fix such issues

Below I'm using word2vec approach which rather than just converting the utterances to vectors using TFIDF approach (losing the semantic information contained in that particular sentence), it maintains the semantic info.

To understand more about word2vec, refer this blog :

[1]https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2017/06/word-embeddings-count-word2veec/

Below is the code for predicted the intent using word2vec approach (Note - It's same as your code, just instead of using TFIDFVectorizer, I'm using word2vec to obtain the vectors. Also the code is divided into different functions to get a good overview of logics that will be evident by there names).

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from gensim.models import Word2Vec
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.svm import SVC

def preprocess_lower(token):
    #utility for preprocessing
    return token.lower()

def load_data(file_name):
    # load a csv file in memory
    return pd.read_csv(file_name)


def process_training_data(training_data):
    # process the training data and split it between independent and dependent variables
    training_sentences = [list(map(preprocess_lower,sentence.split(" "))) for sentence in list(training_data.Utterence.values)]
    target_class = training_data.Intent.values
    label_encoded_Y = preprocessing.LabelEncoder().fit_transform(list(target_class))
    return target_class, training_sentences, label_encoded_Y


def process_user_query(training_data):
    # process the training data and split it between independent and dependent variables
    training_sentences = [list(map(preprocess_lower,sentence.split(" "))) for sentence in training_data]
    return training_sentences

def train_word2vec_model(train_sentences_list):
    # training word2vec on sentences list (inputted by user)
    model = Word2Vec(train_sentences_list, size=100, window=4, min_count=1, workers=4)
    return model

def convert_training_data_vectors(model, train_sentences_list):
    #get the sentences average vector
    training_sectences_vector = list()
    for sentence in train_sentences_list:
        sentence_vetor = [list(model.wv[token]) for token in sentence if token in model.wv.vocab ]
        training_sectences_vector.append(list(np.mean(sentence_vetor, axis=0)))
    return training_sectences_vector

def training_rf_prediction_model(training_data_vectors, label_encoded_Y):
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
# training model on user inputted data 
rf_model = RandomForestClassifier()
# here use the split function and divide the data into training and testing 
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(training_data_vectors,label_encoded_Y,
train_size=0.8,test_size=0.2)
rf_model.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = rf_model.predict(x_test)
print(accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
return rf_model

def training_svm_prediction_model(training_data_vectors, label_encoded_Y):
    svm_model = SVC(gamma='auto')
    svm_model.fit(training_data_vectors, label_encoded_Y)
    return svm_model

def process_data_flow(file_name):
    training_data = load_data(file_name)
    target_class, training_sentences, label_encoded_Y = process_training_data(training_data)
    word2vec_model = train_word2vec_model(train_sentences_list=training_sentences)
    training_data_vectors = convert_training_data_vectors(word2vec_model, train_sentences_list=training_sentences)
    prediction_model = training_rf_prediction_model(training_data_vectors, label_encoded_Y)
    #intent prediction on user query
    userQuery = ["i want apple watch"]
    user_query_vectors = convert_training_data_vectors(word2vec_model, process_user_query(userQuery))
    predicted_class = prediction_model.predict(user_query_vectors)[0]
    predicted_intent = target_class[list(label_encoded_Y).index(predicted_class)]
    return predicted_intent

print("Predicted class: ", process_data_flow("sample_intent_data.csv"))
```

sample data file is in csv format, you just need to format and paste the data in below format :

```
#sample_input_data.csv
Utterence,Intent
hi can I have an Apple Watch,service
how much I will be paying monthly,service
you still around,YOU_THERE
are you still there,YOU_THERE
you there,YOU_THERE
Speak to me if you are there,YOU_THERE
you around,YOU_THERE
```

Also note, your training data should contain good amount of training utterances for each intents for the approach to work.

For accuracy, you can use below approach:

Divide the data into training and testing (mention the split ratio) :

```
x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test=train_test_split(training_vectors,label_encoded_Y,
train_size=0.8,
test_size=0.2)
```

And after training the model, use predict function on x_test to get the predictions. Now just match the prediction for testing data from the model and actual from the data set and you will be able to easily determine the accuracy.

Edit: Added the accuracy score calculation while predicting.

Comment: I got the point you are making but there is issue I tried your code for my requiremnt that is ```1. Train and test my model on sample csv with Utterence and intent and get the accuracy first 2. Then run my model on different set of utterences csv to get the classifier classify their intent and reproduce in that csv file``` from that i can calculate recall precision and f1 score using classification_report of scikit. Is that possible from your code?

Comment: refer this link for integrating the calculation of precision and recall from above code using sklearn : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_precision_recall.html

Comment: finding precision recall is not the issue that I can do the problem is point 1 and point 2 in the above mentioned comment which I am not able to do from your code...can you help me on this

Comment: For the first part, you need to make changes to training_rf_prediction_model function (changes added to above code).

Comment: For second part, you need to run the prediction and after getting the output match with label_encoded_Y (for prediction data only) and use confusion matrix to derive precision and recall.

Comment: Here there is no need of ```userQuery``` as I have to train my model on sample.csv and and run that model to another csv which has just ```utterences``` and need to have the intents of those utterences. Hope i made my problem statement clear

Comment: So you need to just load the query data from another csv as I did for training data, convert to a list of tokens and call the prediction function as it was done in the training function. Just follow the steps I did during training using the rf_model. (And also retrain word2vec on data present in another csv that you had mentioned)

Comment: I tried that but to no avail 3 times i ran the model for  single utterence and all three times it is getting tagged to different intents which was the same problem as with tfidf...so the problem still persists...can you change ur code above

Comment: What's the actual size of the dataset and also the number of intents??

Comment: dataset of 3100 and 75 intents

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199689/discussion-between-abheet22-and-sachin-kumar).